# Creating polyline between points using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, voronoi-thiessen, concave-hull

Using ArcGIS Desktop, I am trying to create a frontline of a battle from WW2. I have known points, and want a polyline to run between both sides. There is 87 days of combat, so every day there is a new frontline as units move.

The image below is an example of one day.

I originally tried using Thiessen polygons, but it's to inaccurate, especially when you have an outlier that juts out.

Do you have any ideas or thoughts?
Dataset
[image: Dataset]
Thieseen Polygons. Its not to bad, but there is that jut in the top right area with the purple polygon.
[image: Thiessen]
Concave Hull example. I need a tighter fit and the red concave to not overlap any yellow points. 
[image]

Comment: Proximity polygons are your best bid. Perhaps smooth boundary after dissolve. You are lucky do not have multipart polygons.